# Add a delay time between thread group iterations

Tags: timer, jmeter, iteration, delay, threadgroup

I have a script with one Thread Group, and I have a look count on so when I run the test it will do 4 iterations of that one thread group.

I am trying to add a delay between each iteration of the thread group NOT between each request in the thread group so that after the first iteration it will wait 5 minutes then do the next iteration.

I have looked all over for a solution but all answers refer to each request as opposed to the entire thread group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add [Flow Control Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) at the start of thread group with Pause Action

> Duration
>   How long to pause for (milliseconds)
>
> This sampler can also be useful in conjunction with the Transaction Controller, as it allows pauses to be included without needing to generate a sample. For variable delays, set the pause time to zero, and add a Timer as a child.

Comment: How about using the timer delay?

Answer (score 0):

[JMeter Timers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/comprehensive-guide-using-jmeter-timers/):

1. Obey JMeter [Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules)
2. Are being executed **before** samplers

So if you want a fixed delay between iterations just add a [Constant Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) as a child of the first [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) in the Thread Group and the delay will be applied.